# Why is this a dense set? (Lemma 6.13, Lee ISM)

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

In Lemma 6.13 of Lee's 'Introduction to Smooth Manifolds' Lee is showing that the images of two functions $\kappa, \tau$ are subsets of measure zero in $\mathbb{RP}^{N-1}$. It follows then that their union $\operatorname{im}(\kappa) \cup \operatorname{im}(\tau)$ is also a measure zero set and finally he uses a small lemma which shows that the complement of a measure zero set is a dense set, that is $\mathbb{RP}^{N-1}\setminus(\operatorname{im}(\kappa) \cup \operatorname{im}(\tau))$ is dense in the projective space. I don't understand how it then follows that the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$ whose equivalence classes are contained in $\mathbb{RP}^{N-1}\setminus(\operatorname{im}(\kappa) \cup \operatorname{im}(\tau))$ are a dense subset *of $\mathbb{R}^N$*. What is the formal reason that this set is dense in $\mathbb{R}^N$? Intuitively, i understand that the equivalence class of any vector is an uncountable set and so if they are dense, surely the vector in plain Euclidean space are dense too. But i fail to find a really formal argument for the claim. Any help would be nice.

The cited proof can be found in Google Books: https://books.google.de/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&lpg=PA125&hl=de&pg=PA132#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: To approximate an element $0\neq v\in \mathbb{R}^N$ you can approximate $\|v\|^{-1}v$, say by norm-one representatives $v_1,v_2,...$ of elements of your set and then $\|v\|v_n$ approximates $v$. To approximate $0$ it is enough to take a representative $v$ of one element of your set and do $n^{-1}v$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you elaborate a bit on your approach? For example, which definition of dense subset are you using? For me saying a subset is dense means its closure gives the whole space. So I suppose you try to show somehow that the close of the set of vectors in $\R^N$ gives the whole of $\R^N$? Or is it easier to use another definition?